# Number of Bit Operation in fast multiplication Algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Determine  a  Value  for  the  constant  $C$  and  use  it  to  estimate  the      number  of  bit  operations  needed  to  multiply  two 64-bit integers using the **Fast Multiplication Algorithm**

Attempt/Analysis-:

Let me write the recursive equation for **Fast Multiplication**   ([Karatsuba_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm))

$f \left(2n\right)$=$3*f \left(n\right)+C*n$

As The bit operations involves 3 operation -:

$1 .\text{Shift operation} $

$2 .\text{Add operation} $

$3 .\text{Subtract operation} $

$\Rightarrow \text{I know that shifting $n$ places would require n bit operation.} $

$\Rightarrow \text{I know that Addition of 2$n$ bit number  would require atmost $3n$ bit operation.} $

$\Rightarrow \text{I know that Subtraction of 2$n$ bit number  would require atmost $3n$ bit operation.} $

I am unable to move forward ....please help me out...answer is $50$n